Is astrology real according to Hinduism?
I am a staunch unsupporter of astrology, numerology and other stuff....
I started analysing religious scriptures of different religions and started searching for proof against astrology in almost all religions.
I have got successful results in Islam; Christianity(Judaism also as it is in old testament); Buddhism; Sikhism and Jainism.
But I couldn't find any proof in Hinduism.... Can yall tell me if Hinduism asks if we should believe in astrology or not? [My conscience says that Hinduism should oppose such stuff as nearly all the other religions say the same thing]
And please cite scriptures and verses as I might need proof
Edit: I am asking about predictive astrology and not the scientific part of jyotisha which calculates the motion of the stars and stuff..
Edit 2: Does Hinduism really says that some stars can change our future???

Yes, astrology is certainly accepted in Hinduism for making predictions. It was common for the Rishis (sages) in the olden times to give astrological predictions to the Grihasthas (family men).
Here's an example from the Bhagavata Purana where Nanda Maharaja, the father of Krishna and Balarama desires to know their future from Garga Muni, an expert in astrology.

ज्योतिषामयनं साक्षाद् यत्तज्ज्ञानमतीन्द्रियम् ।
प्रणीतं भवता येन पुमान् वेद परावरम् ॥ ५ ॥

O great saintly person, you have compiled the astrological knowledge
by which one can understand past and present unseen things. By the
strength of this knowledge, any human being can understand what he has
done in his past life and how it affects his present life. This is
known to you.
Purport by Srila Prabhupada: Nanda Mahārāja was trying to take advantage of the opportunity
afforded by Garga Muni’s presence, for Garga Muni was a great
authority in this knowledge of astrology, by which one can see the
unseen events of past, present and future. It is the duty of a father
to understand the astrological position of his children and do what is
needed for their happiness. Now, taking advantage of the opportunity
afforded by the presence of Garga Muni, Nanda Mahārāja suggested that
Garga Muni prepare a horoscope for Nanda’s two sons, Kṛṣṇa and
Balarāma.
त्वं हि ब्रह्मविदां श्रेष्ठ: संस्कारान्कर्तुमर्हसि ।
बालयोरनयोर्नृणां जन्मना ब्राह्मणो गुरु: ॥ ६ ॥

My lord, you are the best of the brāhmaṇas, especially because you are
fully aware of the jyotiḥ-śāstra, the astrological science. Therefore
you are naturally the spiritual master of every human being. This
being so, since you have kindly come to my house, kindly execute the
reformatory activities for my two sons (Shrimad Bhagavatam 10.8.5-6)

As per the above verse, one fully conversant in jyotiḥ-śāstra (scriptures dealing with astrology) is naturally a Guru for all human beings.
Similarly, when Parikshit was born, King Yudhistira asks specific questions from the sages after hearing their astrological predictions, to know further about his nephew's future for the protection of Dharma.

śrī-rājovāca
apy eṣa vaṁśyān rājarṣīn
puṇya-ślokān mahātmanaḥ
anuvartitā svid yaśasā
sādhu-vādena sattamāḥ

The good King [Yudhiṣṭhira] inquired: O great souls, will he become as
saintly a king, as pious in his very name and as famous and glorified
in his achievements, as others who appeared in this great royal
family?
Purport by Srila Prabhupada: The forefathers of King Yudhiṣṭhira were all great saintly kings,
pious and glorified by their great achievements. They were all saints
on the royal throne. And therefore all the members of the state were
happy, pious, well behaved, prosperous and spiritually enlightened.
Under strict guidance of the great souls and spiritual injunctions,
such great saintly kings were trained up, and as a result the kingdom
was full of saintly persons and was a happy land of spiritual life.
Mahārāja Yudhiṣṭhira was himself a replica of his ancestors, and he
desired that the next king after him become exactly like his great
forefathers. He was happy to learn from the learned brāhmaṇas that by
astrological calculations the child would be born a first-grade
devotee of the Lord, and more confidentially he wanted to know whether
the child was going to follow in the footsteps of his great
forefathers. That is the way of the monarchical state. The reigning
king should be a pious, chivalrous devotee of the Lord and fear
personified for the upstarts. He must also leave an heir apparent
equally qualified to rule over the innocent citizens (Shrimad Bhagavatam 1.12.18).

Astrology is generally not given as much importance as the other scriptures like Upanishads and Bhagavad Gita which deal with topics of enlightenment. But it does hold importance for certain practical matters.

So you are saying astrology is actually supported in Hinduism??? How?? Can I stop my karma if I wear some kind of ring or smth?

it is not what he said in the answer. The answer quotes srimad bhagavatam and illustrates how by knowing your tendencies you can be best engaged in the service of the Lord, which is the effective way to stop your karma. If you have more questions you can ask them in a separate question. comments are for clarification only. cheers.

Astrology never change karma. No one can. Astrology is just a tool to understand what an individual will go through. A spiritual apt can use astrology as tool to understand his/her past karmas. Individual can nullify the debt. Remedies won’t work, actual astrologers will never talk about remedies. Only fake/greedy one will.

But then how is it possible? Suppose an astrologer tells a child he will grow up to join a profession A; what if the child doesn't join that profession?? it is completely up to the child to see what he likes and then will join the profession?? It is free will

I have found the astrology scriptures to be accurate, but more than 90% of astrologers make things up or don't know things the proper way. But yes, fate can be changed by remedies. Astrology is not about predicting, but areas and expected trends in life which can certainly change any time due to pure devotion, good deeds or some other events .
